# Length of plain text from it's SHA1

Tags: security, passwords, sha1, plaintext, string-length

In my website registration, for security reason, I hash password in client side and send the hashed version to server in registration request. But on the server-side, again for security reasons, I want to make sure that the entered password is longer than a specific length.
Is this a way for getting the length of a string from it's SHA1? If no, what other solution do you suggest for my situation to handle both mentioned security issues.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do length check on the client side before hashing? I guess that is how it normally goes in proper sites. In some corporate intranets I saw server side password length validation. I did not bother to view the page's code, but I assume you can have onSubmit handler copying password textfield content length into some hidden <input>?

Comment: Hashing a password at the client doesn't really improve security. Just use HTTPS.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Why wouldn't it improve security?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: I have described how it can improve security in a comment in another post at this thread. But anyway, using HTTPS for both register and login time sounds more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

There is now way to do this. I you really want to hash it client side you should do the length checking client side before you hash it. [Here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/#.USdDQqVLPzW) are some tips on that.

A better way to do it though, is to just do the registration using HTTPS. That way the password is protected.

Problem with doing hashing and such by your self is that is could be done wrong. SHA-1 is for example deprecated. PS. Remember to use salt if you hash.

A con of https is off course that is opens up for possible man in the middle attack. If it really high security you could do both. This is most probably very overkill.

Answer (score 1):

### Don't do that.

Hashing a password on the client and compare the hash to the stored one on the server. is **equivalent to storing plain text passwords**.

An attacker has no need to know the actual password, it's like the hash has become the password.

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that I want to send the hashed password ONLY in registration. In login, client sends the plain text password (in a safe channel) to server, and on the server, this password will be hashed and compared to hashed version which is stored in server. So, this way, it's not gonna be equivalent to storing plain text password.

Comment: You are right, this makes it less dangerous. But you are not *increasing* security either. Use the same channel for registration that you are using for login and you'll be fine.

Comment: Wy don't you want to use HTTPS on registration?